# Rig model with existing armature

Tags: rigging

I imported a model from a game that already has it's own weighted armature.

I was wondering if there is away to use that armature to rig the model to use in Blender.

I've spent quite a long time looking up how to do but, I haven't been able to find a answer.

[image]

Comment: Please add some more infos or share the .blend file: which format did you use for import? Is the rig working badly or not working at all?, etc.....

Comment: It was imported as a .fbx from 3dsmax and like I said the armature is already weighted. I just can't figure out how to rig it without completely remaking the armature

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5235" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5235/)

Answer (score 1):

So in short, you have a "deform rig" and you would like to combine it with a complete rig like rigify (which includes its own deform rig, controllers rig, mechanical rig, ...)?

Sadly it isn't possible. Not in an automated way I mean. You can't mix two different rigs and expect them to work together, they don't know how to "communicate" with each other.

But you have different options to choose from:

- Start from the original deform rig and manually build your own controls and mechanics around.
- Discard the original deform rig and create a whole new one with rigify.
- Try to rename the meshes's vertex groups to the corresponding rigify's deform bones so that the rigify rig uses the original vertex groups for deformation, and make some adaptations when needed.

There isn't one best solution IMHO, they each have their pros and cons. But depending on your situation and goals, some might be more adapted.
If you just want to have an animation ready rig as soon as possible and you feel comfortable with retargeting weights, then the third option looks fine.
If you want your rig asap but don't quite enjoy the tricks of retargeting, then the second option looks more appropriate.
If you want to learn how to rig and skin, then the first option is hand on the best. Or even start from scratch, it's even more instructive.
If you know how to rig, then... Well, whatever, really.

Answer (score 0):

The rig is working.
Just go to object mode, select the rig, go to pose mode, select a bone and move it.

[image]

Comment: What about with rigify? I thought that was the rig. Everytime I try rigify on the armature... it generates a rig but, not correctly.

I'm sorry if I'm doing it wrong. I'm still very new to using Blender.

Comment: In order to use Rigify you should delete the old rig, add an human metarig, in edit mode adapt the bones to stay in the appropriate position in relation with your model, then click "Create rig" in the armature properties panel: hide or delete the metarig, select the model, shift select the new rig, press Ctrl P choosing the "Automatic weight" option. The Rigify rig is way more a better rig than the existing one (but it's also more complex).